# Printing getchar() return value in C

Tags: c

I have a very simple program as the following:

```
int main()
{
  char c;
  while (c = getchar() != 'q')
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

I have two problems running this program:

1. When I run it, it does not print the `c` it has got from `getchar()`. Following is a sample of output: each line is my input, but it does not print it after it gets it:

   ```
   w
   r 
   3
   ```
2. I have defined `q` to quit the program. But when I run it, it does not matter if I input more than one character. If I enter a string that has `q` somewhere in it, it quits the program. For example, the following input will end it:

   ```
   lqw
   ```

How comes `getchar()` has returned `q` after entering `lqw`?

Comment: 2. "How comes `getchar()` has returned `q` after entering `lqw`?" Because `getchar()` does not read strings. It reads *every* keypress you type, including `newline`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is operator precedence. Let's add parentheses so you see how the compiler executes it:

```
c = (getchar()!='q')
```

`!=` has higher precedence than assignment. So `c` is always assigned either 1 or 0. To fix this, do the following:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != 'q' && c != EOF)
```

Why an `int`? Because that's what `getchar` returns. `EOF` is not a `char`, but an `int` value. It has to be, because it's supposed to mean "no valid char". And the check for it is added because if you redirect input into your program, you will get stuck in an infinite loop if `'q'` is never in the input stream.